# Challenge while updating multiple inputs in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

UpdateSliderInput not working...

Hi All,

Seems like a challenge updating sliderInput. So i wanted to develop an application in a way so that filter can be applied dynamically wherein one of the variables needs to be provided with a slider.

Any help can be really appriciable.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(6, actionButton('addFilter', 'Add filter')),
        offset = 6
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholderAddRemFilt'),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholderFilter'),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholderFilter')
      # width = 4 # sidebar
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  filter <- character(0)

  makeReactiveBinding("aggregFilterObserver")
  aggregFilterObserver <- list()

  observeEvent(input$addFilter, {
    add <- input$addFilter
    filterId <- paste0('Filter_', add)
    colfilterId <- paste0('Col_Filter_', add)
    rowfilterId <- paste0('Row_Filter_', add)
    removeFilterId <- paste0('Remove_Filter_', add)
    headers <- names(mtcars)
    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholderFilter',
      # ui = tags$div(id = filterId,
      #               actionButton(removeFilterId, label = "Remove filter", style = "float: right;"),
      #               selectInput(colfilterId, label = "Some Filter", choices = as.list(headers), selected = 1),
      #               sliderInput(rowfilterId, label = "Select variable values",
      #                                  min = 1, max = 2, value = 1:4)
      # )
      ui = tags$div(column(9,id = filterId,
                           actionButton(removeFilterId, label = "Remove filter", style = "float: right;"),
                           selectInput(colfilterId, label = "Some Filter", choices = headers, selected = NULL),
                           conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.",colfilterId," != 'mpg'"),
                                            checkboxGroupInput(rowfilterId, label = "Select variable values",
                                                               choices = NULL, selected = NULL, width = 4000)),
                           conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.",colfilterId," == 'mpg'"),
                                            sliderInput(rowfilterId,
                                                        label = 'select values',
                                                        min = 1,#min(datafile$Age),
                                                        max = 10,#max(datafile$Age),
                                                        value = 1:5))#c(min(datafile$Age),max(datafile$Age))))
      )
      )
    )

    observeEvent(input[[colfilterId]], {

      col <- input[[colfilterId]]
      values <- as.list(unique(mtcars[col]))[[1]]
      print(values)
      print(paste0("example",as.list(unique(mtcars[col]))))
      # 
      # updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, rowfilterId , label = "Select variable    values", 
      #                          choices = values, selected = values, inline = TRUE)
      # 
      updateSliderInput(session, rowfilterId , min = min(values), max = max(values), value = c(min(values),max(values)))
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, rowfilterId , label = "Select variable    values", 
                               choices = values, selected = values, inline = TRUE)

      aggregFilterObserver[[filterId]]$col <<- col
      aggregFilterObserver[[filterId]]$rows <<- NULL
    })

    observeEvent(input[[rowfilterId]], {

      rows <- input[[rowfilterId]]

      aggregFilterObserver[[filterId]]$rows <<- rows

    })

    observeEvent(input[[removeFilterId]], {
      removeUI(selector = paste0('#', filterId))

      aggregFilterObserver[[filterId]] <<- NULL

    })
  })

  output$data <- renderTable({

    dataSet <- mtcars

    invisible(lapply(aggregFilterObserver, function(filter){

      dataSet <<- dataSet[which((dataSet[[filter$col]] %in% filter$rows)), ]

    }))

    dataSet
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Mpg values are not being updated, Is this due to conditionalPanel because of which the sliderInput is not being updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to be perfect apart from the inputid you are using for 2 input types.

I just created one more variable for Sliderinput which will create dynamic input id.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(6, actionButton('addFilter', 'Add filter')),
        offset = 6
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholderAddRemFilt'),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholderFilter'),
      width = 4 # sidebar
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  filter <- character(0)

  makeReactiveBinding("aggregFilterObserver")
  aggregFilterObserver <- list()

  observeEvent(input$addFilter, {
    add <- input$addFilter
    filterId <- paste0('Filter_', add)
    colfilterId <- paste0('Col_Filter_', add)
    rowfilterId <- paste0('Row_Filter_', add)
    rowfilterId_num <- paste0('Row_Filter_num_', add)
    removeFilterId <- paste0('Remove_Filter_', add)
    headers <- names(mtcars)
    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholderFilter',
      ui = tags$div(id = filterId,
                    actionButton(removeFilterId, label = "Remove filter", style = "float: right;"),
                    selectInput(colfilterId, label = "Some Filter", choices = as.list(headers), selected = 1),
                    sliderInput(rowfilterId_num, label = "Select variable values",
                                       min = 1, max = 2, value = 1:4)
      )
    )

    observeEvent(input[[colfilterId]], {
      print(rowfilterId)
      print(paste0(input[[colfilterId]]))

      col <- input[[colfilterId]]
      values <- as.list(unique(mtcars[col]))[[1]]
      print(values)
      print(paste0("example",as.list(unique(mtcars[col]))))

      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, rowfilterId , label = "Select variable    values",
                               choices = values, selected = values, inline = TRUE)

      updateSliderInput(session, rowfilterId_num , label = "Select variable",min = min(values), max = max(values), value = c(min(values),max(values)))
      aggregFilterObserver[[filterId]]$col <<- col
      aggregFilterObserver[[filterId]]$rows <<- NULL
    })

    observeEvent(input[[rowfilterId]], {

      rows <- input[[rowfilterId]]

      aggregFilterObserver[[filterId]]$rows <<- rows

    })

    observeEvent(input[[removeFilterId]], {
      removeUI(selector = paste0('#', filterId))

      aggregFilterObserver[[filterId]] <<- NULL

    })
  })

  output$data <- renderTable({

    dataSet <- mtcars

    invisible(lapply(aggregFilterObserver, function(filter){

      dataSet <<- dataSet[which((dataSet[[filter$col]] %in% filter$rows)), ]

    }))

    dataSet
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

just check and let me know that this is what you wanted to achieve. let me know incase any thing else is required.